# navbar-nav li link should remain active when nav-tabs is switching between tabs (it doesn't)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

On my index page: (main tabs)

```
  <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" bs-active-link>
            <li><a href="#/">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/activiteiten">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/profiel">Profiel</a></li>
```

On my tabs page: (sub tabs) - (ex.: profiel/georganiseerde)

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#/activiteiten">
            <p3>Georganiseerde</p3>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#/deelnemende">
            <p3>Deelnemende</p3>
        </a>
    </li>
```

1) When I go to "profiel main tab" "georganiseerde tab" is active.
BUT
2) When I go to "Deelnemende tab" profiel GOES back INACTIVE while it should remain active.

I already use this code to have my main tabs active. (Found it on stack overflow - Tx!)

```
 angular.module('WebApp')
        .directive('bsActiveLink', ['$location', function ($location) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A', //use as attribute
                replace: false,
                link: function (scope, elem) {
                    //after the route has changed
                    scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
                        var hrefs = ['/#' + $location.path(),
                                     '#' + $location.path(), //html5: false
                                     $location.path()]; //html5: true
                        angular.forEach(elem.find('a'), function (a) {
                            a = angular.element(a);
                            if (-1 !== hrefs.indexOf(a.attr('href'))) {
                                a.parent().addClass('active');
                            } else {
                                a.parent().removeClass('active');
                            };
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
```

---

*Tools:*
I used this tutorial.(https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/building-angularjs-app-tutorial) Very good except the menu collapse did not work.
But I solved that issue already.
I also solved the issue with the main active links tx to Stackoverflow.

Many Tx for your help! B.

Comment: I suggest that if you found the answer, instead of editing the question, please post it as an answer and mark it as such.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I believe that the code provided is the code which doesn't work. Also, you'll want to provide accurate edit comments; "was missing an enter" neither explains what nor why you made such drastic, meaning-changing edits.

Comment: The "was missing an enter " was actually my second edit,  to fix a typo on my first one. I must have deleted it.  Apologies.  As for the question, you are incorrect. The first set of code is wrong, whereas the second is correct.

Comment: The code which is provided works for <ul class="nav navbar-nav" bs-active-link> this. The problem - I already explained above. Tx to check.

Comment: Anybody who can help me out please? Tx Bart